# Use a class from subfolder in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following project architecture :

src/
----main.py
----dir/
--------aclass.py
--------`__init__`.py

I want to use a class defined in aclass.py. I've followed severals tutorials, my init file is empty and I have tried to call aclass using different ways but it never worked.

```
from dir.aclass import Aclass
```

or

```
from aclass import Aclass
```

Do you have any idea where my problem could come from ? I'm using Python 2.7 and Linux Mint.

The error message is :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message (traceback), and from where do you want to import your class ?

Comment: @Guillaume, done, sorry !

Comment: That error should point to the statement with the syntax error. Post that as well! You likely have a syntax error in ``aclass.py``

Comment: Where is the file located that contains this code?

Comment: Assuming your shown code resides in `main.py`, I've have successfully tested your package structure in Python 2 and 3.  Your error likely stems from a typo in your `aclass` module.

Comment: @pylang, I honestly don't know where the problem could come from, I've checked and rechecked, there is no typo, the architecture of the project is exactly the way I described in my first post.